# collection view with bottom aligned variable sized items

Tags: ios, macos, uicollectionview, nscollectionview

I have a collection view with variable sized items. Works fine. But the items are center aligned on a line, as shown in this picture (extracted from Apple's doc)

[image]

What's the simplest way to make them bottom aligned (for both  uicollectionview and nscollectionview) ?

Comment: Are you coding with Swift or Objective C ?

Comment: I use Objective-C.